# Using HAVING clause on function result in select

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm troubled how to use `HAVING` clause avoiding function calling twice.

here is my qry:

```
select col1, col2, dbo.someFunction(param1, param2) as col3
from...
where ...
group ...
having dbo.someFunction(param1, param2) > 0
```

if I wrote

```
having col3 > 0
```

server sais: `Invalid column name 'col3 '.`

Is there a way to use `HAVING` in shown situation without calling function dbo.someFunction twice?

EDIT

my execution plan with having:
[image]

and without having (commented):
[image]

Select without function in select:
[image]

Comment: Why are you comparing with and without having?   That changes the query - yes you will should get different plans.   Compare with and without the function in the select.

Comment: @Blam Yes, you are right.
Updated with no function in select. It looks like there is no difference, thats good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it is calling it twice?

I get the same execution plan from the following two queries

```
select enumID 
from docSVenum1
group by enumID 
having COUNT(*)  > 2000  


select enumID, count(*) as ccount
from docSVenum1
group by enumID 
having COUNT(*)  > 2000
```

Comment: We won't know for sure if the OP doesn't post the execution plan he's getting. The optimizer can generate different execution plans depending on multiple factors like JOINS, amount of data in tables etc. Even if you do get the same execution plan for your example, it won't guaranteevthe same result for the OP.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu See paragraph one

Answer (score 0):

In order not to call the function twice but refer to the result that is returned in column `col3` you'll need another SELECT statement around your query, like below.

```
SELECT col1,
    col2,
    col3
FROM
   (SELECT col1, 
       col2, 
       dbo.someFunction(param1, param2) AS col3 
   FROM ... 
   WHERE... ) AS Result
GROUP BY ...
HAVING col3 > 0
```

You can't reference a column by its alias on the same "nesting level" of the SELECT, which is why you'll have to surround your initial result in another SELECT statement, from which you will be able to reference the column by its alias.

Comment: I think that would lose use of indexes on the group by.